# Must stripe destinations by account ids in order to make a charge

Tags: stripe-payments

Is there anyway to make a customer be the recipient of a charge? From everything I see, it appears that the platform would have to create a stripe account for any individual that may receive charges on the platform. The following code works as long as the destination is a stripe account. Inside destination, I would like to be able to make the destination a customer instead of a stripe account, but I get errors when changing the destination[account] to destination[customer] as well as when I use a customer id in destination[account].

```
var arbitrary_charge = 100;    
stripe.charges.create({
                    amount: arbitrary charge,
                    currency: "usd",
                    customer: stripe_customer_key,
                    destination: {
                        amount: .8*arbitrary_charge, //https://stripe.com/docs/connect/destination-charges
                        account: "acct_xxxxxxxxxxxx"
                    },
                }).then(function(charge) {
                     console.log(charge)
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to make a **Customer** the destination.

When developing a Platform there are two functions you're generally interested in, **paying out** and **taking payments**.

Stripe divides these functions up into separate object types: **Accounts** and **Customers**, respectively. You may have a case where you want to pay out AND take payments, in which case you'll usually want to create both a Customer and Account object for a given entity. Stripe also added a feature recently that allows you to [debit from some Accounts](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/account-debits).

Answer (score 0):

to charge the customer and credit it to the connected account you have to do something like this

```
charge = Stripe::Charge.create({
      amount: amount,
      currency: "usd",
      card: token.id,
      description: "Charge for #{email}",
      receipt_email: email,
     }, {stripe_account: stripe_user_id})
```

stripe_user_id is the account id of the connected account of format "acct_xxxxxxxxxxxx"